# After making a layer visible, map.getCanvas() does not contain the layer immediately. mapbox-gl-js

Tags: png, visibility, layer, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to set some layers' layout visible property to 'visible' using the 'setLayoutProperty' method in mapbox-gl-js.

```
this.toggleCanvasMarkersVisibility(true); // This code sets visibility to visible
// Create a snapshot of the map as follows:
this.map.getCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
                canvasContext.strokeStyle = '#CCCCCC';
                canvasContext.strokeRect(leftPosition, topPosition, width, height);
                var img = new Image();
                img.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous");
                var srcURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                img.onload = function () {
                    canvasContext.drawImage(img, leftPosition, topPosition, width, height);
// Other operations
});
```

The layers which I just set to 'visible' are not visible yet on the map. How do I detect if they are visible other than the visible property, because the 'visible' property is set to 'visible'?
The PNG as a result does not consist of the markers.
Any help is appreciated!